# Returning certain characters from string - BOOST STRING

Tags: c++, string, boost

Does boost string have any methods that might assist me in returning a certain no of characters from a string if their position is specified.
For instance something like

```
Left(std::string("Hello"),2)
```

might return "He".
I checked the library page at [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/string_algo.html) but could not find anyhing.

Comment: *"return 2"* makes no sense, please explain what you really want. Or, f you really want what you said: `int Left(std::string,int i){return i;}`.

Comment: `mystring.substr(0,2)`, no need for Boost.

Comment: Andy just did. Yes, I should have made that an answer.

Comment: @DanielFrey: Sorry for "stealing" the answer, I was just looking up the link for `substr()` and preparing the example when your comment appeared - I wouldn't have posted otherwise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `std::string`'s member function [`substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr):

```
std::string("Hello").substr(0, 2);
```

Here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/48Ihhx%2445).